# Add a custom form on the post-new.php admin page

Tags: plugins, customization, admin

i need to add a custom form  on the post-new0.php page of the admin of wordpress. ( this form will load an external script in ajax and fill all the field) I'm able to do it via my plugin with

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'my_echo_function');
```

But it print it at the top of the page, how can i do to print it as i show on the image ? ( just above the title post text area). ny idea ? Thank you.

EDIT: it can be before or after th wp form this is where i print it right now:

[image: where its printed]

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 1):

WordPress 3.7 has an [`edit_form_top` hook](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L420) that may be what you need.

```
add_action('edit_form_top', 'my_echo_function');
```

Though you will need to write logic to keep it from executing on any but the `post-new.php` page.

Comment: It should be outside the wp form, because i'm addming a new <form>

Comment: I don't think that is going to be easy. Why not work with the form you already have?

Comment: Because it's different, my form do somethimg all, it post some variable somewhere else

Comment: But your question mentions AJAX. It doesn't matter if it is the same form or not. Don't use a `<form>` tag and manipulate everything with Javascript-- kind of like the "custom fields" meta box. In other words, you have decided on a solution that is fighting uphill all the way. Rethink the solution and use what you have available.